# Automating Buffer Wizard in ArcGIS Desktop by working in Shell

Tags: arcpy, buffer, performance, shell

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.x.

I am trying to automate the Buffer Wizard since I have several large sets of the data that I need to buffer at multiple distances. Doing it by hand will take a long time and be quite tedious, but I've already compared buffer times: even arcpy scripting with the buffer tool takes longer than using the Buffer Wizard by hand.

I do not have experience working in the Shell, so I am wondering whether this is feasible?